# Minimal object add-on UI with sub-meshes and Redo

Tags: python, mesh, objects, interface, add-on

I finally have this working UI, after exploring many rabbit-holes, so wanted to share it in the hope of improving its performance.
Follow-up to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/281775/sub-panels-for-the-add-object-template).

The key goal is to preserve the 'redo' action of the add-on template.

**Background**

Learning some OOP has really helped me with this.
My add-on requires the rebuilding of parent mesh as submeshes are added/enabled/altered,
hence the need to 'redo' the object operator.
Expected usage would be for a few submeshes, 100 enabled submeshes would be very unlikely, but...

**Help**

The 'draw' method was helped along by examining Blender's built-in Sapling add-on code.
Also [this snippet](https://blenderartists.org/t/scene-propertygroup-in-operator-before-execute/1463676/8) by @Gorgious on Blenderartists in 2011.

**Positives**

On the whole I find it easy to understand and manage. I will continue to flesh it out for debugging as a "real-user".
Having 'always visible' items in the 'subs' EnumProperty could act as a warning to a user not to register more than necessary.
(Disabling a submesh will need to also disable its child meshes)

**Negatives**

I suspect this is simply not up to scratch for a good add-on.
I admit numbered attribute names in 'SubMeshSpecs' are not Pythonic; numbered attributes are 'removed' by making a list of new instances on 'execute', re-formatted for use as input argument.
Though of course that duplicates what is already present in 'self'. Not sure how abominable this is.

**Usage**

When added to scene, only main mesh properties show.

[image: Main properties].

Selecting a submesh shows its properties; enable to include it

[image: Sub_1 properties].

Enabling a 2nd submesh shows properties for Sub_2.

[image: Sub_1 properties].

Thus the list if sub_attributes grows with only enabled submeshes

```
    if sub_attributes:
        print(sub_attributes)
    # sub_attributes after 2 submeshes are enabled and edited
    # [SubMesh(end='E', parent='0', length=4, SubMesh(end='N', parent='1', length=1]
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?
(I guess I mean without numbered attributes, or creating SubMesh in a more Blendery way.)

In particular, if the enabled default is set to True and "user_pref_num_subs" set to a high number, the drag on performance (delay) is noticeable, even without adding meshes, whenever a value is changed.
I would prefer the meshes to be the cause of a delay, not the UI.

````
bl_info = {
    "name": "New Object",
    "author": "Your Name Here",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Add > Mesh > New Object",
    "description": "Adds a new Mesh Object",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Add Mesh",
}

# pylint: disable="no-member,wrong-import-position,line-too-long"

import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty, IntProperty, BoolProperty, EnumProperty
from bpy_extras.object_utils import AddObjectHelper, object_data_add
from mathutils import Vector


user_pref_num_subs = 5
range_subs = range(1, user_pref_num_subs + 1)

items = [(str(sub_idx), f"Sub_{sub_idx}", "") for sub_idx in range(user_pref_num_subs + 1)]
items[0] = ('0', "Main", "")


def add_object(self, context):

    sub_attributes = []
    for sub_idx in range_subs:
        include = getattr(self, f"enabled{sub_idx}")
        if include:
            sub_mesh = SubMesh(
                end=getattr(self, f"end{sub_idx}"),
                parent=getattr(self, f"parent{sub_idx}"),
                length=getattr(self, f"length{sub_idx}")
            )
            sub_attributes.append(sub_mesh)

    if sub_attributes:
        print(sub_attributes)

    # add-on starts here with arguments in desired format
    # MyAddOn(self, sub_attributes)

    scale_x = self.scale.x
    scale_y = self.scale.y

    verts = [
        Vector((-1 * scale_x, 1 * scale_y, 0)),
        Vector((1 * scale_x, 1 * scale_y, 0)),
        Vector((1 * scale_x, -1 * scale_y, 0)),
        Vector((-1 * scale_x, -1 * scale_y, 0)),
    ]

    edges = []
    faces = [[0, 1, 2, 3]]

    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name="New Object Mesh")
    mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)

    object_data_add(context, mesh, operator=self)


class SubMesh:
    """ A submesh specification """

    def __init__(self, end, parent, length):
        self.end = end
        self.parent = parent
        self.length = length

    def __repr__(self):
        class_name = type(self).__name__
        return f"{class_name}(end={self.end!r}, parent={self.parent!r}, length={self.length!r}"


def annotations() -> dict:
    """ Generates numbered properties per submesh """
    props = {}
    for sub_idx in range_subs:
        props.update({
            f"enabled{sub_idx}": BoolProperty(name="Enable selected", description="Make submesh visible",
                                            default=False),
            f"end{sub_idx}": EnumProperty(name="End", description="Direction this mesh faces",
                                        items=[('E', "East (+x)", ""), ('N', "North (+y)", ""),
                                               ('W', "West (-x)", ""), ('S', "South (-y)", "")]),
            f"parent{sub_idx}": EnumProperty(name="Parent", description="Parent of this mesh",
                                           items=items),
            f"length{sub_idx}": IntProperty(name="Length", description="Length (tile-count)",
                                          default=2)
        })
    return props

data = {
    'bl_label': "Simple Object Operator",
    'bl_idname': "object.submesh_operator",
    '__annotations__': annotations()
}

SubMeshSpecs = type("SubmeshOperator", (Operator,), data)


class OBJECT_OT_add_object(SubMeshSpecs, Operator, AddObjectHelper):
    """Create a new Mesh Object"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.add_object"
    bl_label = "Add Mesh Object"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    scale: FloatVectorProperty(name="Scale", description="scaling",
                               default=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), subtype='TRANSLATION')
    subs : EnumProperty(name="Select", description="Alter settings of this mesh",
                        items=items)

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        box = layout.box()
        row = box.row()
        row.prop(self, "subs")
        if self.subs == '0':
            row = layout.row()
            row.prop(self, "scale")
        for sub_idx in range_subs:
            if self.subs == str(sub_idx):
                row = layout.row()
                col = row.column()
                col.prop(self, f"enabled{sub_idx}")
                col = row.column()
                col.prop(self, f"end{sub_idx}")
                row = col.row()
                row.prop(self, f"parent{sub_idx}")
                row = layout.row()
                row.prop(self, f"length{sub_idx}")


    def execute(self, context):

        add_object(self, context)

        return {'FINISHED'}


# Registration

def add_object_button(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(
        OBJECT_OT_add_object.bl_idname,
        text="Add Object",
        icon='PLUGIN')


bl_classes = [
    SubMeshSpecs,
    OBJECT_OT_add_object
]


def register():
    for bl_class in bl_classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(bl_class)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.append(add_object_button)


def unregister():
    for bl_class in bl_classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(bl_class)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.remove(add_object_button)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````

Comment: Not sure I understand what this addon does, or what the goal is. Could you explain the use case, or show the indended workflow? Maybe show an example of usage, along with some screenshots or better yet a short [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963).

Comment: I have added the Usage paragraph with screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it takes a bad script to find a good one; I apologize for anything misleading in the question and its code.

This seems to be the way forward, and is mercifully short, which is a good sign.

I think I gave up on the idea of a CollectionProperty in Operators because of registration issues, but [this `draw()` snippet](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102446/how-to-generate-temporary-operators-with-dynamic-properties) works fine.

````
bl_info = {
    "name": "New Object",
    "author": "Your Name Here",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Add > Mesh > New Object",
    "description": "Adds a new Mesh Object",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Add Mesh",
}

import time
import bpy
from bpy.props import (StringProperty, BoolProperty, EnumProperty,
                        IntProperty, FloatVectorProperty, CollectionProperty)


USER_PREF_MAX_SUBS = 10
RANGE_SUBS = range(1, USER_PREF_MAX_SUBS + 1)
items = [(str(sub_idx), f"Sub_{sub_idx}", "") for sub_idx in range(USER_PREF_MAX_SUBS + 1)]
items[0] = ('0', "Main", "")


def progress(starttime, msg):
    """ measure blocks of code """
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(msg, end - starttime)


class SubMeshSpec(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    """ A submesh specification """
    enabled: BoolProperty(name="Enable selected", description="Make submesh visible",
                          default=False)
    end: EnumProperty(name="End", description="Direction this mesh faces", default='E',
                      items=[('E', "East (+x)", ""), ('N', "North (+y)", ""),
                                               ('W', "West (-x)", ""), ('S', "South (-y)", "")])
    parent: EnumProperty(name="Parent", description="Parent of this mesh",
                         items=items)
    length: IntProperty(name="Length", description="Length (tile-count)",
                        default=2)


class OBJECT_OT_add_object(bpy.types.Operator):
    """ Collection Operator """
    bl_idname = 'mesh.add_object'
    bl_label = 'Add a mesh object.'
    bl_description = 'Adds a mesh object to the scene.'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    submesh_specs: CollectionProperty(type=SubMeshSpec)

    scale: FloatVectorProperty(name="Scale", description="scaling",
                               default=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), subtype='TRANSLATION')
    subs : EnumProperty(name="Select", description="Alter settings of this mesh",
                        items=items)

    def __init__(self):
        """ Preload collection once only

        Blender can't see __init__(); not triggered on redo
        """
        for _ in RANGE_SUBS:
            self.submesh_specs.add()

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        box = layout.box()
        row = box.row()
        row.prop(self, "subs")
        if self.subs == '0':
            row = layout.row()
            row.prop(self, "scale")

        for sub_idx in RANGE_SUBS:
            if self.subs == str(sub_idx):
                row = layout.row()
                col = row.column()
                row.label(text=f"Edit Sub_{sub_idx}")
                col = row.column()
                col.prop(self.submesh_specs[sub_idx], 'enabled')
                row = layout.row()
                col = row.column()
                col.prop(self.submesh_specs[sub_idx], 'end')
                row = col.row()
                row.prop(self.submesh_specs[sub_idx], 'parent')
                row = layout.row()
                row.prop(self.submesh_specs[sub_idx], 'length')

    def execute(self, context):
        atts = []
        start = time.perf_counter()
        print(self.submesh_specs)
        for sub in self.submesh_specs:
            if sub.name != 'Main':
                if sub.enabled is True:
                    sub_mesh = SubMesh(
                        end=sub.end,
                        parent=sub.parent,
                        length=sub.length,
                    )
                    atts.append(sub_mesh)
        if atts:
            print(atts)
        # e.g. [
        #     SubMesh(end='E', parent='0', length=2,
        #     SubMesh(end='N', parent='1', length=3
        # ]
        progress(start, "add_ob")

        return {'FINISHED'}


class SubMesh:
    """ A submesh specification class """

    def __init__(self, end, parent, length):
        self.end = end
        self.parent = parent
        self.length = length

    def __repr__(self):
        class_name = type(self).__name__
        return f"{class_name}(end={self.end!r}, parent={self.parent!r}, length={self.length!r}"


def add_object_button(self, context):
    """ Button on the Add > Mesh menu """
    self.layout.operator(
        OBJECT_OT_add_object.bl_idname,
        text="Add Object",
        icon='PLUGIN')


bl_classes = [
    SubMeshSpec,
    OBJECT_OT_add_object
]


def register():
    """ Register classes """
    for bl_class in bl_classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(bl_class)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.append(add_object_button)


def unregister():
    """ Unregister classes """
    for bl_class in bl_classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(bl_class)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.remove(add_object_button)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```
````